# optimal size of innodb buffer pool

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf, buffer-pool

I read a lot of optimal number of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and people say it must be larger with 10% than the innodb tables size, what is `60M`. Accordyngly this the optimal size of the buffer is about `66M` im my case.
Should I set this value more than 66M, for example `256M` or `1G` to achieve better performance? I have enough memory to add more to innodb buffer pool if that improve the performance.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you expect your InnoDB data to grow, you should prepare for it by having a larger InnoDB Buffer Pool.

Where does the idea of having additional 10% extra space for the Buffer Pool come from ???

Please note the following diagram of the InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Look in the upper left hand corner where you see the buffer pool. There is a section of it called the "Insert Buffer Part". [The purpose of the Insert Buffer is to populate changes to non-unique indexes into the Insert Buffer inside the system tablespace file (a.k.a. ibdata1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-insert-buffering.html).

From the diagram, up to 50% of the Buffer Pool can be used to manage the Insert Buffer. That being the case, it would be in your best interests to assign a lot more memory to the Buffer Pool. With a data set of 60M, 256M would be a great place to start,

Comment: Extra 10% of buffer pool is used for control structures. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), the recommended size is "up to 80% of system memory".   Or more specifically, most people will recommend 50-80% of memory.

I think you are misquoting the 10% figure for the approximate overhead that will be required on top of whatever you allocate.